# Force WKWebView to show mobile version

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to force WKWebView to show mobile version.  I am getting inconsistent results across app versions.  But, safari always sows mobile correctly.   I have tried setting the userAgent, nothing seems to affect the view.

Comment: For me, If I load a URL with a URLRequest, the mobile version is displayed. If I load it with The HTMLString, then it shows the desktop version. I'm not sure why, though...

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I found the correct solution was to clear the cache when launching the app.

Swift:

```
class func clearWebCache(){
    let websiteDataTypes = NSSet(array: [
        WKWebsiteDataTypeDiskCache,
        WKWebsiteDataTypeOfflineWebApplicationCache,
        WKWebsiteDataTypeMemoryCache,
        WKWebsiteDataTypeLocalStorage,
        WKWebsiteDataTypeCookies,
        WKWebsiteDataTypeSessionStorage,
        WKWebsiteDataTypeIndexedDBDatabases,
        WKWebsiteDataTypeWebSQLDatabases])
    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
    WKWebsiteDataStore.defaultDataStore().removeDataOfTypes(websiteDataTypes as! Set<String>, modifiedSince: date, completionHandler:{ })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 9 version of WKWebView, there is a property customUserAgent. Please, try to change this property :

```
// User Agent
webview.customUserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPod; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; ja-jp) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5";

// refresh webview
[webview reloadFromOrigin];
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked to see how modern sites are determining that a browser (and thus an app with a web view) are considered mobile.  One of the more prominent PHP-based analyzers ([MobileDetect](http://mobiledetect.net)) uses a combination of several factors.  It looks for the presence of "mobile" headers, but these are generally for older devices.  Then, it does Regular Expression matching based on user agent.  Here are the specific strings it matches against:

```
protected static $phoneDevices = array(
    'iPhone'        => '\biPhone\b|\biPod\b', // |\biTunes
    'BlackBerry'    => 'BlackBerry|\bBB10\b|rim[0-9]+',
    'HTC'           => 'HTC|HTC.*(Sensation|Evo|Vision|Explorer|6800|8100|8900|A7272|S510e|C110e|Legend|Desire|T8282)|APX515CKT|Qtek9090|APA9292KT|HD_mini|Sensation.*Z710e|PG86100|Z715e|Desire.*(A8181|HD)|ADR6200|ADR6400L|ADR6425|001HT|Inspire 4G|Android.*\bEVO\b|T-Mobile G1|Z520m',
    'Nexus'         => 'Nexus One|Nexus S|Galaxy.*Nexus|Android.*Nexus.*Mobile|Nexus 4|Nexus 5|Nexus 6',
    // @todo: Is 'Dell Streak' a tablet or a phone? ;)
    'Dell'          => 'Dell.*Streak|Dell.*Aero|Dell.*Venue|DELL.*Venue Pro|Dell Flash|Dell Smoke|Dell Mini 3iX|XCD28|XCD35|\b001DL\b|\b101DL\b|\bGS01\b',
    'Motorola'      => 'Motorola|DROIDX|DROID BIONIC|\bDroid\b.*Build|Android.*Xoom|HRI39|MOT-|A1260|A1680|A555|A853|A855|A953|A955|A956|Motorola.*ELECTRIFY|Motorola.*i1|i867|i940|MB200|MB300|MB501|MB502|MB508|MB511|MB520|MB525|MB526|MB611|MB612|MB632|MB810|MB855|MB860|MB861|MB865|MB870|ME501|ME502|ME511|ME525|ME600|ME632|ME722|ME811|ME860|ME863|ME865|MT620|MT710|MT716|MT720|MT810|MT870|MT917|Motorola.*TITANIUM|WX435|WX445|XT300|XT301|XT311|XT316|XT317|XT319|XT320|XT390|XT502|XT530|XT531|XT532|XT535|XT603|XT610|XT611|XT615|XT681|XT701|XT702|XT711|XT720|XT800|XT806|XT860|XT862|XT875|XT882|XT883|XT894|XT901|XT907|XT909|XT910|XT912|XT928|XT926|XT915|XT919|XT925|XT1021|\bMoto E\b',
    'Samsung'       => 'Samsung|SM-G9250|GT-19300|SGH-I337|BGT-S5230|GT-B2100|GT-B2700|GT-B2710|GT-B3210|GT-B3310|GT-B3410|GT-B3730|GT-B3740|GT-B5510|GT-B5512|GT-B5722|GT-B6520|GT-B7300|GT-B7320|GT-B7330|GT-B7350|GT-B7510|GT-B7722|GT-B7800|GT-C3010|GT-C3011|GT-C3060|GT-C3200|GT-C3212|GT-C3212I|GT-C3262|GT-C3222|GT-C3300|GT-C3300K|GT-C3303|GT-C3303K|GT-C3310|GT-C3322|GT-C3330|GT-C3350|GT-C3500|GT-C3510|GT-C3530|GT-C3630|GT-C3780|GT-C5010|GT-C5212|GT-C6620|GT-C6625|GT-C6712|GT-E1050|GT-E1070|GT-E1075|GT-E1080|GT-E1081|GT-E1085|GT-E1087|GT-E1100|GT-E1107|GT-E1110|GT-E1120|GT-E1125|GT-E1130|GT-E1160|GT-E1170|GT-E1175|GT-E1180|GT-E1182|GT-E1200|GT-E1210|GT-E1225|GT-E1230|GT-E1390|GT-E2100|GT-E2120|GT-E2121|GT-E2152|GT-E2220|GT-E2222|GT-E2230|GT-E2232|GT-E2250|GT-E2370|GT-E2550|GT-E2652|GT-E3210|GT-E3213|GT-I5500|GT-I5503|GT-I5700|GT-I5800|GT-I5801|GT-I6410|GT-I6420|GT-I7110|GT-I7410|GT-I7500|GT-I8000|GT-I8150|GT-I8160|GT-I8190|GT-I8320|GT-I8330|GT-I8350|GT-I8530|GT-I8700|GT-I8703|GT-I8910|GT-I9000|GT-I9001|GT-I9003|GT-I9010|GT-I9020|GT-I9023|GT-I9070|GT-I9082|GT-I9100|GT-I9103|GT-I9220|GT-I9250|GT-I9300|GT-I9305|GT-I9500|GT-I9505|GT-M3510|GT-M5650|GT-M7500|GT-M7600|GT-M7603|GT-M8800|GT-M8910|GT-N7000|GT-S3110|GT-S3310|GT-S3350|GT-S3353|GT-S3370|GT-S3650|GT-S3653|GT-S3770|GT-S3850|GT-S5210|GT-S5220|GT-S5229|GT-S5230|GT-S5233|GT-S5250|GT-S5253|GT-S5260|GT-S5263|GT-S5270|GT-S5300|GT-S5330|GT-S5350|GT-S5360|GT-S5363|GT-S5369|GT-S5380|GT-S5380D|GT-S5560|GT-S5570|GT-S5600|GT-S5603|GT-S5610|GT-S5620|GT-S5660|GT-S5670|GT-S5690|GT-S5750|GT-S5780|GT-S5830|GT-S5839|GT-S6102|GT-S6500|GT-S7070|GT-S7200|GT-S7220|GT-S7230|GT-S7233|GT-S7250|GT-S7500|GT-S7530|GT-S7550|GT-S7562|GT-S7710|GT-S8000|GT-S8003|GT-S8500|GT-S8530|GT-S8600|SCH-A310|SCH-A530|SCH-A570|SCH-A610|SCH-A630|SCH-A650|SCH-A790|SCH-A795|SCH-A850|SCH-A870|SCH-A890|SCH-A930|SCH-A950|SCH-A970|SCH-A990|SCH-I100|SCH-I110|SCH-I400|SCH-I405|SCH-I500|SCH-I510|SCH-I515|SCH-I600|SCH-I730|SCH-I760|SCH-I770|SCH-I830|SCH-I910|SCH-I920|SCH-I959|SCH-LC11|SCH-N150|SCH-N300|SCH-R100|SCH-R300|SCH-R351|SCH-R400|SCH-R410|SCH-T300|SCH-U310|SCH-U320|SCH-U350|SCH-U360|SCH-U365|SCH-U370|SCH-U380|SCH-U410|SCH-U430|SCH-U450|SCH-U460|SCH-U470|SCH-U490|SCH-U540|SCH-U550|SCH-U620|SCH-U640|SCH-U650|SCH-U660|SCH-U700|SCH-U740|SCH-U750|SCH-U810|SCH-U820|SCH-U900|SCH-U940|SCH-U960|SCS-26UC|SGH-A107|SGH-A117|SGH-A127|SGH-A137|SGH-A157|SGH-A167|SGH-A177|SGH-A187|SGH-A197|SGH-A227|SGH-A237|SGH-A257|SGH-A437|SGH-A517|SGH-A597|SGH-A637|SGH-A657|SGH-A667|SGH-A687|SGH-A697|SGH-A707|SGH-A717|SGH-A727|SGH-A737|SGH-A747|SGH-A767|SGH-A777|SGH-A797|SGH-A817|SGH-A827|SGH-A837|SGH-A847|SGH-A867|SGH-A877|SGH-A887|SGH-A897|SGH-A927|SGH-B100|SGH-B130|SGH-B200|SGH-B220|SGH-C100|SGH-C110|SGH-C120|SGH-C130|SGH-C140|SGH-C160|SGH-C170|SGH-C180|SGH-C200|SGH-C207|SGH-C210|SGH-C225|SGH-C230|SGH-C417|SGH-C450|SGH-D307|SGH-D347|SGH-D357|SGH-D407|SGH-D415|SGH-D780|SGH-D807|SGH-D980|SGH-E105|SGH-E200|SGH-E315|SGH-E316|SGH-E317|SGH-E335|SGH-E590|SGH-E635|SGH-E715|SGH-E890|SGH-F300|SGH-F480|SGH-I200|SGH-I300|SGH-I320|SGH-I550|SGH-I577|SGH-I600|SGH-I607|SGH-I617|SGH-I627|SGH-I637|SGH-I677|SGH-I700|SGH-I717|SGH-I727|SGH-i747M|SGH-I777|SGH-I780|SGH-I827|SGH-I847|SGH-I857|SGH-I896|SGH-I897|SGH-I900|SGH-I907|SGH-I917|SGH-I927|SGH-I937|SGH-I997|SGH-J150|SGH-J200|SGH-L170|SGH-L700|SGH-M110|SGH-M150|SGH-M200|SGH-N105|SGH-N500|SGH-N600|SGH-N620|SGH-N625|SGH-N700|SGH-N710|SGH-P107|SGH-P207|SGH-P300|SGH-P310|SGH-P520|SGH-P735|SGH-P777|SGH-Q105|SGH-R210|SGH-R220|SGH-R225|SGH-S105|SGH-S307|SGH-T109|SGH-T119|SGH-T139|SGH-T209|SGH-T219|SGH-T229|SGH-T239|SGH-T249|SGH-T259|SGH-T309|SGH-T319|SGH-T329|SGH-T339|SGH-T349|SGH-T359|SGH-T369|SGH-T379|SGH-T409|SGH-T429|SGH-T439|SGH-T459|SGH-T469|SGH-T479|SGH-T499|SGH-T509|SGH-T519|SGH-T539|SGH-T559|SGH-T589|SGH-T609|SGH-T619|SGH-T629|SGH-T639|SGH-T659|SGH-T669|SGH-T679|SGH-T709|SGH-T719|SGH-T729|SGH-T739|SGH-T746|SGH-T749|SGH-T759|SGH-T769|SGH-T809|SGH-T819|SGH-T839|SGH-T919|SGH-T929|SGH-T939|SGH-T959|SGH-T989|SGH-U100|SGH-U200|SGH-U800|SGH-V205|SGH-V206|SGH-X100|SGH-X105|SGH-X120|SGH-X140|SGH-X426|SGH-X427|SGH-X475|SGH-X495|SGH-X497|SGH-X507|SGH-X600|SGH-X610|SGH-X620|SGH-X630|SGH-X700|SGH-X820|SGH-X890|SGH-Z130|SGH-Z150|SGH-Z170|SGH-ZX10|SGH-ZX20|SHW-M110|SPH-A120|SPH-A400|SPH-A420|SPH-A460|SPH-A500|SPH-A560|SPH-A600|SPH-A620|SPH-A660|SPH-A700|SPH-A740|SPH-A760|SPH-A790|SPH-A800|SPH-A820|SPH-A840|SPH-A880|SPH-A900|SPH-A940|SPH-A960|SPH-D600|SPH-D700|SPH-D710|SPH-D720|SPH-I300|SPH-I325|SPH-I330|SPH-I350|SPH-I500|SPH-I600|SPH-I700|SPH-L700|SPH-M100|SPH-M220|SPH-M240|SPH-M300|SPH-M305|SPH-M320|SPH-M330|SPH-M350|SPH-M360|SPH-M370|SPH-M380|SPH-M510|SPH-M540|SPH-M550|SPH-M560|SPH-M570|SPH-M580|SPH-M610|SPH-M620|SPH-M630|SPH-M800|SPH-M810|SPH-M850|SPH-M900|SPH-M910|SPH-M920|SPH-M930|SPH-N100|SPH-N200|SPH-N240|SPH-N300|SPH-N400|SPH-Z400|SWC-E100|SCH-i909|GT-N7100|GT-N7105|SCH-I535|SM-N900A|SGH-I317|SGH-T999L|GT-S5360B|GT-I8262|GT-S6802|GT-S6312|GT-S6310|GT-S5312|GT-S5310|GT-I9105|GT-I8510|GT-S6790N|SM-G7105|SM-N9005|GT-S5301|GT-I9295|GT-I9195|SM-C101|GT-S7392|GT-S7560|GT-B7610|GT-I5510|GT-S7582|GT-S7530E|GT-I8750|SM-G9006V|SM-G9008V|SM-G9009D|SM-G900A|SM-G900D|SM-G900F|SM-G900H|SM-G900I|SM-G900J|SM-G900K|SM-G900L|SM-G900M|SM-G900P|SM-G900R4|SM-G900S|SM-G900T|SM-G900V|SM-G900W8|SHV-E160K|SCH-P709|SCH-P729|SM-T2558|GT-I9205',
    'LG'            => '\bLG\b;|LG[- ]?(C800|C900|E400|E610|E900|E-900|F160|F180K|F180L|F180S|730|855|L160|LS740|LS840|LS970|LU6200|MS690|MS695|MS770|MS840|MS870|MS910|P500|P700|P705|VM696|AS680|AS695|AX840|C729|E970|GS505|272|C395|E739BK|E960|L55C|L75C|LS696|LS860|P769BK|P350|P500|P509|P870|UN272|US730|VS840|VS950|LN272|LN510|LS670|LS855|LW690|MN270|MN510|P509|P769|P930|UN200|UN270|UN510|UN610|US670|US740|US760|UX265|UX840|VN271|VN530|VS660|VS700|VS740|VS750|VS910|VS920|VS930|VX9200|VX11000|AX840A|LW770|P506|P925|P999|E612|D955|D802|MS323)',
    'Sony'          => 'SonyST|SonyLT|SonyEricsson|SonyEricssonLT15iv|LT18i|E10i|LT28h|LT26w|SonyEricssonMT27i|C5303|C6902|C6903|C6906|C6943|D2533',
    'Asus'          => 'Asus.*Galaxy|PadFone.*Mobile',
    // http://www.micromaxinfo.com/mobiles/smartphones
    // Added because the codes might conflict with Acer Tablets.
    'Micromax'      => 'Micromax.*\b(A210|A92|A88|A72|A111|A110Q|A115|A116|A110|A90S|A26|A51|A35|A54|A25|A27|A89|A68|A65|A57|A90)\b',
    // @todo Complete the regex.
    'Palm'          => 'PalmSource|Palm', // avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|plucker|xiino ;
    'Vertu'         => 'Vertu|Vertu.*Ltd|Vertu.*Ascent|Vertu.*Ayxta|Vertu.*Constellation(F|Quest)?|Vertu.*Monika|Vertu.*Signature', // Just for fun ;)
    // http://www.pantech.co.kr/en/prod/prodList.do?gbrand=VEGA (PANTECH)
    // Most of the VEGA devices are legacy. PANTECH seem to be newer devices based on Android.
    'Pantech'       => 'PANTECH|IM-A850S|IM-A840S|IM-A830L|IM-A830K|IM-A830S|IM-A820L|IM-A810K|IM-A810S|IM-A800S|IM-T100K|IM-A725L|IM-A780L|IM-A775C|IM-A770K|IM-A760S|IM-A750K|IM-A740S|IM-A730S|IM-A720L|IM-A710K|IM-A690L|IM-A690S|IM-A650S|IM-A630K|IM-A600S|VEGA PTL21|PT003|P8010|ADR910L|P6030|P6020|P9070|P4100|P9060|P5000|CDM8992|TXT8045|ADR8995|IS11PT|P2030|P6010|P8000|PT002|IS06|CDM8999|P9050|PT001|TXT8040|P2020|P9020|P2000|P7040|P7000|C790',
    // http://www.fly-phone.com/devices/smartphones/ ; Included only smartphones.
    'Fly'           => 'IQ230|IQ444|IQ450|IQ440|IQ442|IQ441|IQ245|IQ256|IQ236|IQ255|IQ235|IQ245|IQ275|IQ240|IQ285|IQ280|IQ270|IQ260|IQ250',
    // http://fr.wikomobile.com
    'Wiko'          => 'KITE 4G|HIGHWAY|GETAWAY|STAIRWAY|DARKSIDE|DARKFULL|DARKNIGHT|DARKMOON|SLIDE|WAX 4G|RAINBOW|BLOOM|SUNSET|GOA|LENNY|BARRY|IGGY|OZZY|CINK FIVE|CINK PEAX|CINK PEAX 2|CINK SLIM|CINK SLIM 2|CINK +|CINK KING|CINK PEAX|CINK SLIM|SUBLIM',
    'iMobile'        => 'i-mobile (IQ|i-STYLE|idea|ZAA|Hitz)',
    // Added simvalley mobile just for fun. They have some interesting devices.
    // http://www.simvalley.fr/telephonie---gps-_22_telephonie-mobile_telephones_.html
    'SimValley'     => '\b(SP-80|XT-930|SX-340|XT-930|SX-310|SP-360|SP60|SPT-800|SP-120|SPT-800|SP-140|SPX-5|SPX-8|SP-100|SPX-8|SPX-12)\b',
     // Wolfgang - a brand that is sold by Aldi supermarkets.
     // http://www.wolfgangmobile.com/
    'Wolfgang'      => 'AT-B24D|AT-AS50HD|AT-AS40W|AT-AS55HD|AT-AS45q2|AT-B26D|AT-AS50Q',
    'Alcatel'       => 'Alcatel',
    'Nintendo' => 'Nintendo 3DS',
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoi
    'Amoi'          => 'Amoi',
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INQ
    'INQ'           => 'INQ',
    // @Tapatalk is a mobile app; http://support.tapatalk.com/threads/smf-2-0-2-os-and-browser-detection-plugin-and-tapatalk.15565/#post-79039
    'GenericPhone'  => 'Tapatalk|PDA;|SAGEM|\bmmp\b|pocket|\bpsp\b|symbian|Smartphone|smartfon|treo|up.browser|up.link|vodafone|\bwap\b|nokia|Series40|Series60|S60|SonyEricsson|N900|MAUI.*WAP.*Browser',
);
```

If you want to be sure to match most sites, try to include some of these elements in your custom user agent header.  I think including 'iPhone' is a smart idea as a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

### iOS 13.0 and above

There is a property, [preferredContentMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebpagepreferences/3194426-preferredcontentmode) in WKWebView to show the mobile version.

```
webView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.preferredContentMode = .mobile
```